# Creating a tiled hex game with Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-engine, hexagonal-tiles, kobold-kit

I'm new to Swift / Objective-C but have been coding Mac and Windows apps / games for years using Xojo (similar to Visual Basic).

I want to make a simple turn-based strategy game with a tiled hex map and I want to do it in Swift for Mac OS X. What technology is best to start with? Can this be achieved with SpriteKit or are there any other open source tile engines I can use with Swift to give me a head start (whilst I could write my own hex engine, I'd rather not as that's not the fun part of making a game!).

Comment: You should ask this kind kind of question on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

There are open source tile engines you can use. "Tiled" is one of the ones I've used, recommended by the ray wenderlich team. It gives a nice visual representation of the map.

Comment: can you provide a link to "Tiled" engine?

Comment: You might want to give a look to Ray Wenderlich website as advised and JSTileMap on github.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually using the new TileMapNode class added to SpriteKit in Xcode 8, iOS 10/macOS 10.12. It's a very elegant solution.